# Windows Service vs. Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: windows-services, workflow-foundation

I need something that runs in the background and go into my database and scan and update certain rows based on certain logic.  I need this to run like every hour and my environment is Windows Server 2003, SqlServer 2005.

Is WWF good for this purpose? Or should I create a Windows Service? And, what's difference between WWF and Windows Service, or just simply what is the best way to just do this?

Thanks,
Ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a windows service if I were you.  I've done a lot of work in WF and the main reason I would say to not do it in WF is that MS is basically completely rewriting the next version of WF according to what MS said at PDC in Oct.  There will be a way to run legacy 3.0/3.5 activities in 4.0, but my impression was that there are going to be major changes.

Also, it sounds like you don't need the modular activity capability that WF provides.  WF is going to add another layer of abstraction that it sounds like you are not going to need, plus you are still going to need to write a windows service to run your workflow that you create.  WF would be a good choice if you had a business person that needed to constantly change the logic that was happening and you wanted to make a big investment in the management of this process you want to create.

Also I agree that based on what you are saying you should consider creating an SSIS package in SQL Server, unless you don't have direct access to the database.

Answer (score 3):

I would say use a windows service not a workflow.  Using a workflow is for when there is a process involved.  As you are just updating records in a table, I would say a service is as good as anything..

Actually, now that I have read your question again, you might want to consider a SQL Server job as well as they can be scheduled to run at whatever interval you like.

A windows service is a long running process that runs in the background in windows.  A Windows Workflow Foundation workflow is used for laying out a workflow for a business process (or something).  You need to host the workflow runtime within something (Console App, ASP.Net, Windows Service, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do run an ASP.NET app on the server.  I just need a background process to scan a table.

Comment: Ya, I would suggest a SQL Server Job then, if all you need to do is run a query on a scheduled interval, that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Windows service had work for me in the past,  workflow primary feature is not scheduling and you will need to provide a host for it, when windows services infrastructure already contains all of this and its also well documented.